# Parsing an array in Gson - Each Object having an identifier - 14th Feb

Tags: java, gson

I have the following JSON string and I am trying to parse it using Google gson. I have tried multiple options but not able to map it into java pojo.

JSON String:

```
[ 
  {
    DRIVER:  {
               "name" : "Tom",
                "age" : 23
             }
  },
  {
     DRIVER :
      {
         "name" : "Dick",
          "age" : 25
      }
  }
]
```

Can anyone please help in guiding me on how to parse this kind of a json string. I am stuck at the point when each JsonObject in the JsonArray contains a linkedhashmap.

Comment: whats the relation to the date though?

Comment: Where is map or LinkedHashMap here? I see only json only list with objects? If this is list, easiest way to make wrap entity, like this:

        class DriverWrap {
             List<Driver> drivers;
        }

Yes, it's not good decision, but helps you fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Wrapper classes to map that data into. Following is a working code according to your provided JSON.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "YOUR JSON STRING"
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        DataWrap[] data = gson.fromJson(json, DataWrap[].class);
        System.out.println(data[0].getDRIVER().getAge());

    }


    public static class DataWrap {

        private Driver DRIVER;

        public Driver getDRIVER() {
            return DRIVER;
        }

        public void setDRIVER(Driver DRIVER) {
            this.DRIVER = DRIVER;
        }
    }

    public static class Driver {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
```